# Is there any way to securly store some credentials as part of Artifactory User Plugin?

Tags: plugins, artifactory

My user plugin will make a POST request to an external server after storing new artifact on a particular path, I need to securely store user credentials required for this request. A typical way that has been handled in couple of other user plugin is to have the credential in a json/yaml configuration files, which is not really great choice for my use case. Is there any other secured way that artifactory suggests?

Comment: Not sure if you are willing to wait a couple of weeks and upgrade, but the next Artifactory version (7.6) will include Webhooks, which allows storing credentials to an Endpoint in a secure manner.

Comment: I definitely could wait for couple of months! Well, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @Ortsigat